# TV mount to Wall Studs

Tags: drywall-anchor, mount

While installing a wall mount for a 48" TV, I realized I made a mistake. I drilled a ⅜ pilot hole in the wall stud and then installed the anchors provided with the mount that the lag bolts would be secured in. Going back to the instructions I realized my mistake, having used the directions for the "Concrete wall installation" instead of the "Wood stud wall installation."

The Concrete wall installation instructions say not to use these for a wood stud installation, but rather to use a 7/32 pilot with the provided lag bolt.

As far as I can tell, the only difference between the concrete and wood stud installation is that the concrete uses the provided anchors, and both use the same 4 lag bolts.

So do I need to fill these holes with wood filler or something and start over, or will the concrete anchors make a difference at all?

Comment: If you use the anchors in wood, they probably can split the wood when tighten.  TV mount should be big enough to cover holes after filling and then make new holes in stud a bit below or above.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use the lag shields, anchors, in wood studs. Wood can compress and the holding power could/would be reduced after a while. Just drill your 7/32" pilot holes about an inch and a half above or below the existing holes.  Remove the anchors and fill the holes with joint compound if they'll show when you mount the bracket in the new location.